# obtener datos de 2 archivo

Tags: python, csv

estoy tratando de hacer lo siguiente: a manera de ejemplo pondré esto, tengo 2 archivos `entrada.txt` y `pr.csv`, el archivo entrada tiene unos 5k registros con `cuenta,etiqueta`, mientras que el archivo pr contiene 100k registro de igual manera cuenta y etiqueta.

lo que estoy tratando de hacer es cruzas la información de entrada contra la de pr para obtener un 3er archivo de salida el cual contendría los 5k registros de entrada junto con las columnas de pr, siempre y cuando coincida la cuenta.

```
entrada.txt
1111111111111111,check1
2222222222222222,check2

pr.csv
1111111111111111,datos1
2222222222222222,datos2
3333333333333333,datos3
4444444444444444,datos4

import csv

salida = open('salida.txt','w')

with open('pr.csv', 'r') as pr:
    lector = csv.reader(pr, delimiter=',')
    datos = [l for l in lector]
    for x in datos:
        cu = x[0]
        lu = x[1]


with open('entrada.txt', 'r') as ent:
    lec = csv.reader(ent, delimiter=',')
    dat = [e for e in lec]

for c in dat:
    if c[0] in cu:
        salida.write(cu +','+
                     lu +','+
                     c[1] +'\n')
    else:
        salida.write(cu +','+
                     lu +','+
                     c[1] +'\n')

salida.close()
```

el archivo `salida.txt` sale de manera correcta con los 5k registros, pero las demás columnas que deberían contener la información de pr si las muetras pero en todas solo me da la misma cuenta y etiqueta repetida.

RESULTADO

```
salida.txt
4444444444444444,datos4,check1
4444444444444444,datos4,check2
```

quisiera saber si estoy pasando o haciendo algo mal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entendí correctamente tu pregunta, quieres que en salida haya exactamente lo mismo que en entrada, sólo que con una "columna" adicional, por así decir, que sería la extraída del fichero pr.csv

El problema de tu código era (entre otros) que las variables `cu` y `lu` se sobreescribían en cada iteración del bucle, por lo que no recordaban valores anteriores, sino sólo el de la última iteración. También te puedes ahorrar las comprensiones de listas, pues los objetos devueltos por `csv.reader()` son directamente iterables. Esto no es un error, pero sí se evita la innecesaria creación de las listas intermedias `datos` o `dat`.

Para este caso creo que lo más eficiente será leer el fichero pr.csv en memoria para crear con él un diccionario en el que las claves sean las cadenas del primer campo (111111111, etc) y los valores sean las cadenas del segundo campo (datos1, etc)

Esto puedes crearlo así:

```
pr_dic = {}
with open('pr.csv', 'r') as pr:
    lector = csv.reader(pr, delimiter=',')
    for x in lector:
        cu, cl = x[0], x[1]
        pr_dic[cu] = lu
```

Una vez tenemos este diccionario creado, ya podemos procesar entrada.txt, usando `pr_dic.get()` para obtener los valores asociados con la clave correspondiente a cada línea. Este método `.get()` te permite también especificar un valor por defecto para el caso en que la clave no se encuentre en el diccionario (no sé si este caso es posible, en el ejemplo que has puesto no se produce nunca). He decidido usar una cadena vacía para ese caso.

Ya de paso, utilizo una variante de `with` que permite abrir dos ficheros a la vez para en el mismo bloque abrir el fichero de entrada y el de salida. Quedará así:

```
with open('entrada.txt', 'r') as ent, open('salida.txt','w') as salida:
    lec = csv.reader(ent, delimiter=',')
    for c in lec:
      extra = pr_dic.get(c[0], "")  # La información extra a añadir
      data = c + [extra]
      salida.write(",".join(data) + "\n")
```

El resultado en `salida.txt` es:

```
1111111111111111,check1,datos1
2222222222222222,check2,datos2
```

### Ampliación

A petición del OP indico qué cosas había mal en su código:

- Error de diseño: las variables `cu` y `lu` se sobreescriben una y otra vez en este bucle:

  ```
  for x in datos:
      cu = x[0]
      lu = x[1]
  ```

  Por lo que al final del bucle conterndrán sólo los valores `x[0]` y `x[1]` correspondientes a la última `x` en `datos`. No se van "guardando" valores previos. Para eso sería necesaria una lista o un diccionario
- Error de sintaxis: se usan un par de variables llamadas `dc` y `lc`, que no han sido inicializadas previamente. No obstante, esto no llega a producir error porque las líneas en que se usan esas variables no se ejecutan nunca, debido a que nunca entra por la condición `if c[0] in cu:`
- Errores de lógica. La comparación `c[0] in cu` no tiene sentido, pues `cu` no es una lista ni un diccionario. Es una cadena que contiene "444444..444" pues esa es la última clave leida de `pr.csv`
- No se entiende tampoco qué debería hacerse si la condición fuese cierta, pues no está claro qué son esas variables `dc` y `dl`
- Y si la condición es falsa (que siempre lo es como hemos visto) se realiza el `else:` en el cual se usa en la salida los valores de `cu` y `cl`, lo que tampoco parece tener mucho sentido, ya que si el registro buscado no estaba en `cu` ¿por qué se usa `cu`?

En general es difícil marcar errores particulares que puedan ser corregidos cambiando una línea o dos. La lógica completa es equivocada y requiere un replanteamiento.

Comment: realiza el proceso como tu lo mencionas y sale de manera correcta, me podrías decir que en cosas esta mal mi código y formas de mejorar ya que manipulo mucho este tipo de archivos, saludos.

Comment: gracias @abulafia, por lo visto cometí muchos errores, admito que aun soy un novato y agradecería aun mas si me dijeras como mejorar o encontrar sitios que me puedan ayudar al escribir código en python.  sobre `dc y lc` deberian ser `cu lu` , herror mio. algo que no me queda muy claro es el punto 5 en cuando al else:

Comment: Si cambias `dc`  y `lc` por `cu`, `lu` entonces verás que lo que haces en el `else` es exactamente lo mismo que lo que haces en el `if`, por lo que queda más patente que hay un error de lógica ahí. Realmente no comprendo qué se pretendía. Entiendo que la idea era buscar si la clave actual estaba en el fichero `pr.csv`, para añadir esos datos si estaba, pero ¿y si no estaba? ¿cómo es que haces lo mismo? (aparte de que realmente no se estaba logrando el objetivo por los errores antes señalados)

Comment: se lo que dices al cambiar a `cu lu` else: haría prácticamente lo mismo, mi intención en esa parte era que `else` me arrojara también las cuentas que no encontró pero con alguna etiqueta como `ERROR` o `#NA`, por esa razón trate de iterar y pasarlo por `if` y `else`, alguna idea mejor para obtener lo que menciono?

Comment: Pues la clave la tienes en la explicación de `.get()` que admite un parámetro con el valor a usar por defecto si la clave no se encuentra. Yo puse `""`, puedes poner en su lugar lo que necesites. Por ejemplo `extra = pr_dic.get(c[0], "ERROR")`

Comment: es verdad, creo que pase por alto esa parte y eso que estuve repasando los tutoriales en python, me recomiendas añadir mas diccionarios en caso de que quiera obtener otras columnas? ademas veo que en el diccionario pr_dic{} al iterarlo puedo notar que tanto clave y valor son los mismo, es correcto hacer esto?

Comment: La clave y el valor no son lo mismo (no deberían!). Las claves son 11111... 22222... etc. Los valores son "datos1", "datos2", etc. Si el fichero `pr.csv` tiene más columnas que te interese preservar, una opción puede ser que el valor en el diccionario asociado a cada clave sea una lista con esas columnas que te interesan.

Comment: creo que lo tengo,algo mas si no es molestia, como puedo manipular 2 archivos e igual manera tener un 3 con resultado solo que en esta ocasión los archivos no están limitados por comas sino mas bien por espacios manteniendo siempre la misma estructura algo así `1234567890123456    NOMBRE    1234567890    1234567890    DIRECCION`, donde también se haría un cruce para quitar los teléfonos sin importar en que columna estén, pero sin recorrer ni alterar la estructura quedando así `1234567890123456    NOMBRE                  1234567890    DIRECCION` los espacios pueden variar entre columnas saludos

Comment: Creo que esta consulta debería ir ya en otra pregunta. Así la puedes explicar mejor y poner un ejemplo más extenso del formato exacto de los ficheros

Answer (score 1):

La manera correcta de procesar archivos de gran tamaño (de cualquier tamaño en realidad), es registro a registro, línea a línea. Eso consume un mínimo de memoria y garantiza que el proceso no se va a caer en alguna parte por falta de RAM.

El esquema general de la solución es:

```
Abrir los archivos.
Por cada registro del archivo de entrada, avanzar el archivo maestro hasta encontrar el registro con la misma clave.
Producir la salida con la información disponible.
```

En código que da asi:

```
import csv

with open('salida.txt','w') as salida:
    with open('pr.csv', 'r') as pr:
        maestro = csv.reader(pr, delimiter=',')
        rec_maestro = next(maestro)
        eof_maestro = False
        with open('entrada.txt', 'r') as ent:
            entrada = csv.reader(ent, delimiter=',')
            for rec_entrada in entrada:
                salida.write(f"{rec_entrada[0]},{rec_entrada[1]}")
                while not eof_maestro and rec_maestro[0] < rec_entrada[0]:
                    try:
                        rec_maestro = next(maestro)
                    except StopIteration:
                        eof_maestro = True
                if not eof_maestro and rec_maestro[0] == rec_entrada[0]:
                    salida.write(f",{rec_maestro[1]}")
                salida.write("\n")
```

Comment: El problema de este enfoque es que presupone que las claves en `pr.csv` están ordenadas en el mismo orden que en `entrada.txt`. Si no es así es posible que al ir avanzando `maestro` buscando una clave, te "pases de largo" otra entrada que vaya a aparecer más tarde en `entrada`. Si esto ocurre el algoritmo no funciona. La forma de arreglarlo sería "rebobinar" `maestro` cada vez que se llega al final. Esto puede llegar a ser muy ineficiente en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: Es cierto que sería más eficiente en memoria, y quizás no haya otra forma de atacar el problema si los ficheros son tan enormes que no caben en memoria. Pero si caben, el tema entonces trata de elegir qué se prefiere optimizar, si el uso de memoria o el tiempo de ejecución. Leer `pr.csv` completo en un diccionario usa mucha más memoria, pero acelera muchísimo el tiempo de ejecución, especialmente en el caso de ficheros y claves desordenadas.

Comment: Un profesional de respeto mantiene sus archivos ordenados; es el contrato implicito. Si no es el caso, se informa. Eso, y dado el ejemplo que el OP mostró, me habilitan para asumir que vienen ordenados.

Comment: Mi enfoque es más eficiente, porque sólo tiene lecturas, escrituras y operaciones de comparación entre escalares. No es necesario pedir espacio para listas o diccionarios, ni se necesitan ciclos de reloj para accesar la información.

Comment: Sí, sí. Ya he dicho que tu solución  es más eficiente para el caso de entradas ordenadas. La distinción entre velocidad vs memoria se aplica sólo en el caso en que no vengan ordenadas, ya que en ese caso un enfoque que se base únicamente en procesamiento de ficheros debería leer completo múltiples veces el fichero `pr.csv`.

Comment: en este caso por ser practico coloque los datos en orden en ambos archivos, pero la realidad es que son números de cuentas un un rango de 16 dígitos y están desordenados, claro siempre ocupan la misma columna ademas de contener mas columnas y registros los cuales pueden ir de 1,000 a 100,00 registros

Comment: Si los datos no están en orden, puedes aplicar un sort externo antes de procesarlos.